# How to add a redirection from main url to url-on-sub-domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have created a `sub-domain forum.new4u.com` for the site `new4u.com`.

Actually the forum in  `/web/forum` directory. So forum can also be accessed as `http://news4u.com/forum/index.php` and also at `http://forum.news4u.com/index.php`

Now, I want to redirect all the old forum URLs to new forum URL.

example:

```
http://news4u.com/forum/post_id=225
```

is to be `http://forum.news4u.com/post_id=225`

How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your server technology.

IIS - [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

Apache - [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

nginx - [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

EDIT -

Since you should be using mod_rewrite, you could do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/.]+) http://forum.news4u.com/$1
```

EDIT2 -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.news4u.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /forum/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi.. I added it into .htaccess and it is getting redirected. BUT giving error this way 
The webpage at http://forum.news4u.com/index has resulted in too many redirects.
And after typing http://forum.news4u.com/index.php it is taking only http://forum.news4u.com/index

Comment: Sorry, kind of got my first answer backwards. Added a better, less wrong solution.

Comment: sorry to disturb u again.. I got error again... By pasting edit 2 code, I am not getting redirected..